# Python yield function runs twice instead of once

Tags: python, python-3.x

The objective of the python code below is to take a CSV file, partition it into N CSV files, and write these output files to disk.

Note that each file has to contain complete records, you cannot split records between files.

The `chunk_file.write()` function writes the files. Problem is that the last file is created twice.

```
def read_in_chunks(file_path, chunk_size):

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:

        pending = b''

        while True:

            chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
            if not chunk:
                print('EOF')
                if pending != b'':
                    yield pending
                pending = b''
                break

            print("CHUNK SIZE: " + str(len(chunk)))
            data = pending + chunk
            x1 = data.rfind(b'\n')
            if x1 != -1:
                x2 = len(data) - x1 - 1
                pending = data[-x2:]
                yield data[:x1 + 1]

table_name = 'my_table'
chunk_num = 1
for records_chunk in read_in_chunks('input_file.csv', chunk_size):
    chunk_filename = f'{table_name}_{chunk_num}.csv'
    with open(chunk_filename, 'wb') as chunk_file:
        print("CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:" + str(len(records_chunk)))
        chunk_file.write(records_chunk)
    
    chunk_num += 1
```

When I run this code, the print result is:

```
CHUNK SIZE: 10000
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:9998 
CHUNK SIZE: 10000
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:9984 
CHUNK SIZE: 10000
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:9982 
CHUNK SIZE: 10000
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:10022
CHUNK SIZE: 10000
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:9982 
CHUNK SIZE: 3559
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:3591 
EOF
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:3591
```

Note that the last two file lengths are identical, and the last one is written after the EOF .

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Not sure whether this is the problem, but in the case that `x1 == -1`, do you need to clear out `pending`? At the moment, if `x1 == -1`, then `pending` isn't altered and just retains its value from the previous iteration.

Comment: Yes, if x1 == -1 is very unlikely to happen but I need to deal with it, still that's not the problem

Comment: Right. One more thought, what happens when `data` has `\n` right at the end? Then `x1 == len(data) - 1`, so `x2` becomes 0, and `pending` becomes `data[0:]`. So in that situation, `yield pending` yields the whole of the last value of `data` - which is the same as the chunk you just wrote.

Comment: yes, you are right, that's the answer, if x2 is zero then I need to set pending = b''

Comment: Three questions out of curiosity:

Is it a specific requirement to read the file as bytes, instead of as text directly which would give you the ability to iterate over the lines, removing the bytes processing?

When you say that you must partition the file, what are the requirements of the partitions? Should they be as evenly distributed as possible, or is it specifically a threshold scheme required, like you're using?

Comment: it's not a requirement to handle this with bytes, that's something I need to change. And the only requirement is to partition in manageable chunks that can be manipulated in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure how to answer to your question, because the input file and the expected output are missing, so I am posting code that I have tested with my input file `input.csv` and that was tested using 3 different chunk size, see below, important my code saves each record in a single file:

`input.csv` :

```
Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarrenHouse,312,3.75
Belinda Jameson,2017,CushingHouse,148,3.52
Jeff Smith,2018,PrescottHouse,17-D,3.20
Sandy Allen,2019,OliverHouse,108,3.48
```

My code is:

```
table_name = 'my_table'
chunk_num = 1

from itertools import repeat

def read_in_chunks(file_path, chunk_size):

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:

        pending = b''

        while chunk := f.read(chunk_size):
            
            # print('chunk : ', chunk.hex())
            
            # escapecodes = map(''.join, zip(repeat(r'\x'), *[iter(chunk.hex())]*2))
            
            # print("'", *escapecodes, "'", sep='')
            
            print("CHUNK SIZE: " + str(len(chunk)))
            print('CHUNK : ', chunk, type(chunk))
                
            data = pending + chunk
            
            print('DATA : ', data)

            if  len(data.split(b'\n', 1)[0]) < len(data):
                
                out = data.split(b'\n', 1)[0]
                
                pending = data.split(b'\n', 1)[1]
                
                yield out
                
            else:
                
                pending = data
                            
        print('pending : ', pending)
              
        for i in pending.split(b'\n'):
            
            if i != b'':
                yield i
 
        print('EOF')

### Uncomment to try with one of the 3 different chunk size

# chunk_size = 4
# chunk_size = 40000
chunk_size = 25

for records_chunk in read_in_chunks('input_file.csv', chunk_size):
    chunk_filename = f'{table_name}_{chunk_num}.csv'
    with open(chunk_filename, 'wb') as chunk_file:
        print("CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:" + str(len(records_chunk)))
        chunk_file.write(records_chunk)
    
    print('print(records_chunk) : ', records_chunk)
    
    chunk_num += 1
```

output in both 3 cases using different chunk size: 4, 4000 or 25:

`my_table_1.csv` :

```
Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarrenHouse,312,3.75
```

`my_table_2.csv` :

```
Belinda Jameson,2017,CushingHouse,148,3.52
```

`my_table_3.csv` :

```
Jeff Smith,2018,PrescottHouse,17-D,3.20
```

`my_table_4.csv` :

```
Sandy Allen,2019,OliverHouse,108,3.48
```

printed output using  `chunk_size = 25`:

```
CHUNK SIZE: 25
CHUNK :  b'Sally Whittaker,2018,McCa' <class 'bytes'>
DATA :  b'Sally Whittaker,2018,McCa'
CHUNK SIZE: 25
CHUNK :  b'rrenHouse,312,3.75\nBelind' <class 'bytes'>
DATA :  b'Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarrenHouse,312,3.75\nBelind'
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:43
print(records_chunk) :  b'Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarrenHouse,312,3.75'
CHUNK SIZE: 25
CHUNK :  b'a Jameson,2017,CushingHou' <class 'bytes'>
DATA :  b'Belinda Jameson,2017,CushingHou'
CHUNK SIZE: 25
CHUNK :  b'se,148,3.52\nJeff Smith,20' <class 'bytes'>
DATA :  b'Belinda Jameson,2017,CushingHouse,148,3.52\nJeff Smith,20'
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:42
print(records_chunk) :  b'Belinda Jameson,2017,CushingHouse,148,3.52'
CHUNK SIZE: 25
CHUNK :  b'18,PrescottHouse,17-D,3.2' <class 'bytes'>
DATA :  b'Jeff Smith,2018,PrescottHouse,17-D,3.2'
CHUNK SIZE: 25
CHUNK :  b'0\nSandy Allen,2019,Oliver' <class 'bytes'>
DATA :  b'Jeff Smith,2018,PrescottHouse,17-D,3.20\nSandy Allen,2019,Oliver'
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:39
print(records_chunk) :  b'Jeff Smith,2018,PrescottHouse,17-D,3.20'
CHUNK SIZE: 15
CHUNK :  b'House,108,3.48\n' <class 'bytes'>
DATA :  b'Sandy Allen,2019,OliverHouse,108,3.48\n'
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:37
print(records_chunk) :  b'Sandy Allen,2019,OliverHouse,108,3.48'
pending :  b''
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

ok new answer trying to use your entire code, using my input:

`input.csv`:

```
Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarrenHouse,312,3.75
Belinda Jameson,2017,CushingHouse,148,3.52
Jeff Smith,2018,PrescottHouse,17-D,3.20
Sandy Allen,2019,OliverHouse,108,3.48
```

your amended code :

```
table_name = 'my_table'
chunk_num = 1


def read_in_chunks(file_path, chunk_size):

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:

        pending = b''

        while True:

            chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
            if not chunk:
                print('EOF')
                if pending != b'':
                    
                    print('yield pending :', pending)
                    yield pending
                pending = b''
                break

            print("CHUNK SIZE: " + str(len(chunk)))
            data = pending + chunk
            x1 = data.rfind(b'\n')
            print('x1 : ', x1)
            if x1 != -1:
                
                x2 = len(data) - x1 - 1
                
                print('x2 : ', x2)
                
                if x2 == 0 :
                    pending = b''
                    
                else:
                    pending = data[-x2:]
                    
                yield data[:x1 + 1]
                
                print(data[:x1 + 1])
                print('pending : ', pending)
            else:
                # print('else')
                pending = data


chunk_size = 60

for records_chunk in read_in_chunks('input_file.csv', chunk_size):
    chunk_filename = f'{table_name}_{chunk_num}.csv'
    with open(chunk_filename, 'wb') as chunk_file:
        print("CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:" + str(len(records_chunk)))
        chunk_file.write(records_chunk)
    
    chunk_num += 1
```

output:

`my_table_1.csv`:

```
Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarrenHouse,312,3.75
```

`my_table_2.csv`:

```
Belinda Jameson,2017,CushingHouse,148,3.52
```

`my_table_3.csv`:

```
Jeff Smith,2018,PrescottHouse,17-D,3.20
Sandy Allen,2019,OliverHouse,108,3.48
```

printed output using `chunk_size = 60`:

```
CHUNK SIZE: 60
x1 :  43
x2 :  16
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:44
b'Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarrenHouse,312,3.75\n'
pending :  b'Belinda Jameson,'
CHUNK SIZE: 60
x1 :  42
x2 :  33
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:43
b'Belinda Jameson,2017,CushingHouse,148,3.52\n'
pending :  b'Jeff Smith,2018,PrescottHouse,17-'
CHUNK SIZE: 45
x1 :  77
x2 :  0
CHUNK LENGTH TO WRITE:78
b'Jeff Smith,2018,PrescottHouse,17-D,3.20\nSandy Allen,2019,OliverHouse,108,3.48\n'
pending :  b''
EOF
```